# How to use multiple secrets sources in Spring Cloud Kubernetes

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I have multiple Secret resources in my Kubernetes cluster and I would like to have my Spring Boot application, which uses Spring Cloud Kubernetes, use them.

I have read the [docs on it](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/current/reference/html/#namespace-resolution), but I still cannot wrap my head around it.

My Secret resource looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: service1-secrets
  namespace: my-app-namespace
type: Opaque
data:
  config.service1.pass=<base64-encoded String>
  config.service1.user=<base64-encoded String>
```

I also have a similar Secret resource for other services my application needs.

The secrets are deployed in the same namespace and the ServiceAccount as well as I can see them.

**How do I specify multiple secret sources?** Do I have to use a `bootstrap(-env).yaml` instead of a properties file?

In my `bootstrap.properties` file (for the correct environment, `-azure`), I have:

```yaml
    spring.cloud.kubernetes.secrets.enabled=true
    spring.cloud.kubernetes.enabled=true
    spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.namespace=my-app-namespace
    spring.cloud.kubernetes.client.namespace=my-app-namespace
    spring.cloud.kubernetes.secrets.namespace=my-app-namespace
    spring.cloud.kubernetes.secrets.sources={labels={name=service1-secrets}}, {name=service2-secrets}
```

Unfortunately when starting up the pod, I get the following error:

```bash
{"TIMESTAMP":"2023-03-26 03:34:35,697","SEVERITY":"WARN","APPLICATION":"springAppName_IS_UNDEFINED","CLASS":"o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext","MESSAGE":"Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'secretsPropertySourceLocator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/kubernetes/client/config/KubernetesClientBootstrapConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'secretsPropertySourceLocator' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.cloud.kubernetes.secrets-org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.commons.config.SecretsConfigProperties': Could not bind properties to 'SecretsConfigProperties' : prefix=spring.cloud.kubernetes.secrets, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.cloud.kubernetes.secrets.sources' to java.util.List<org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.commons.config.SecretsConfigProperties$Source>",...}
```

followed by:

```bash
{"TIMESTAMP":"2023-03-26 03:34:35,994","SEVERITY":"ERROR","APPLICATION":"springAppName_IS_UNDEFINED","CLASS":"o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter","MESSAGE":"\n\n***************************\nAPPLICATION FAILED TO START\n***************************\n\nDescription:\n\nFailed to bind properties under 'spring.cloud.kubernetes.secrets.sources' to java.util.List<org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.commons.config.SecretsConfigProperties$Source>:\n\n    Property: spring.cloud.kubernetes.secrets.sources\n    Value: \"{labels={name=service1-secrets}}, {name=service2-secrets}\"\n    Origin: class path resource [config/bootstrap-azure.properties] - 6:41\n    Reason: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.List<org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.commons.config.SecretsConfigProperties$Source>]\n\nAction:\n\nUpdate your application's configuration\n",...}
```

Please note: I am currently not using volumeMounts or environment variables in my `deployment.yaml` file to pass secrets. From what I understand a Spring Cloud Kubernetes enabled application can "discover" or "find" secrets in a given namespace on the actual Kubernetes cluster via API. I know it's rather insecure (or discouraged), but I do not care for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring cloud kubernetes contributor here.

Let's start slow, if you do not mind. First things first is to tell what version are you using of `spring-cloud-kubernetes`. Then, your link that you posted redirects to "namespace resolution" chapter, which is most probably not what you want. You might want to read [this part](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/spring-cloud-kubernetes.html#configmap-propertysource). Though it is specific to ConfigMaps, secrets are computed the same way. So you need a configuration like this (for example):

```
spring:
  application:
    name: cloud-k8s-app
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      secrets:
        namespace: <YOUR_NAMESPACE>
        enableApi: true
        sources:
         - name: secret-1
         - name: secret-2
```

Since you use a single namespace, you can define it at the `secrets` level. If on the other hand you will need to read secrets from *different* namespaces, you will need to change a bit your configuration:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: cloud-k8s-app
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      secrets:
        namespace: <YOUR_NAMESPACE>
        enableApi: true
        sources:
         - name: secret-1
           namespace: namespace_1
         - name: secret-2
```

In this manner, `secret-1` will be read from `namespace_1`, and `secret-2` will be read from `<YOUR_NAMESPACE>`.

---

If you use version `3.x.x` of `spring-cloud-kubernetes`, things might be slightly involved, because we do not support bootstrap (by default), you need to opt-in into it. But that is the only way to read multiple secrets with version `3.x.x` anyway. If that is the case, leave a comment and I will update this answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I had to ensure I use a ServiceAccount, that has sufficient permissions for all relevant namespaces, too. It worked out great, thank you. Just in case some uses a `bootstrap.properties` file: `spring.cloud.kubernetes.secrets.sources[0].name=my-secret` will do (increment index for following sources).